# spring boot with hibernate and postgres giving exception column name not found even it is present

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using native query as below in spring boot with postgres and hibernate.

@Query(value = "SELECT json_data from xxxschema.roles  where role_id =?1", nativeQuery = true)
Role getRolePrivilegesByRoleId(int id);

I'm getting following errors not sure why ?

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name role_id was not found in this ResultSet.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2748) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `Role` but do not return all columns from the query mapped in the `Role` entity.